# calculate load time repeat control

Tags: xpages

Under a repeat control I would like to display a message how long it took to load the data-set for it e.g. "1000 documents loaded in 0.2 seconds".

How can I do this?

The number of elements in the list is easy via getRowCount(). But how can I get the time to collect the data?

Comment: What is the data binding of the repeat?

Comment: a call to a method in a java class

Answer (score 1):

You can put the start value in a scoped variable in the BeforePageLoad event and then access it after the page has loaded. You could use

```
System.nanoTime
```

for both values

Comment: yes, but that is the time for the whole page, not the repeat component.

Comment: @PatrickKwinten: You could save the initial nanoTime to the scope in one of the repeat control's dynamically computed properties. For example, at the beginning of the code for the  computed `value` attribute.